# Pushwoosh: Set Badge with PHP API

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

I'm using a paid Pushwoosh Account in order to send programmatically push-notifications to my users.

I've implemented the [Pushwoosh PHP SDK](https://github.com/gomoob/php-pushwoosh) and everything works great, but I'm not able to set a Notification-Badge on iOS devices as seen on the following image:

[image]

My code so far is:

```
$devicesArr[] = ...

$pushwoosh = Pushwoosh::create()
                        ->setApplication('79XXX-9CXXX')
                        ->setAuth('Wkf...2C8');

//Create the Message
$request = CreateMessageRequest::create()
                        ->addNotification(Notification::create()
                        ->setContent('A new workout is available!')
                        ->setDevices($devicesArr));

//Call the REST Web Service
$response = $pushwoosh->createMessage($request);
```

I tried to use the `->setBadge(5)` method according to [this page](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/setbadge) but this also does not work:

```
$request = SetBadgeRequest::create()
    ->setBadge(1)
    ->setHwid('18D...1AF');
```

Do you know how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: Did your app received notification? when you registered notification, did you set `UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge` for `UIUserNotificationSettings`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using Ionic/Cordova and the [Pushwoosh-Cordova-Plugin](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-plugin) in order to use Pushwoosh. Yes, everything works fine as I'm retrieving the push-notifications (both on iOS and Android). But I'm not able to set a badge count.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this on Cordova Sample (https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-cordova-sample/tree/master/Phonegap-iOS-Android-WP), can you share a simple sample?

Are you sure the app is closed when you receive push with badge?

Comment: Hello. What do you mean with "you can't reproduce this on Cordova Sample"? I think the problem lies in the PHP snippet I posted above. The Pushwoosh/Cordova implementation itself works perfectly. I can set notification-badges with the Pushwoosh.com Dashboard, but not with the PHP API (snippet above).

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, this is not the method you use to set the badge number on the device.

> Important
>
> This method IS NOT used to update the badge value on the device.
>   Instead  please use /createMessage request with the "ios_badges" parameter.
>   http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/setbadge